# Mail movement to subfolder not being reflected in Outlook (IMAP client) when moving mail via another Email SMTP service

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, smtp, microsoft-outlook-2016

When I move mail using SMTP service of some application to inbox's subfolder, the mail is still being shown in inbox in Outlook mailbox which I have configured through IMAP protocol. Why the same is not being reflected in Outlook?

Comment: What kind of "SMTP service" are you using? Generally SMTP is only for submitting mail and does not allow accessing existing mailboxes in any way.

Comment: I am using Automation Anywhere's (RPA tool) Email SMTP service where it takes smtpHost, port, username and password as input.

Comment: Which configuration are you talking about -- [this "Options" window](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-6OoEdz_jB1U/W0RVjYPloaI/AAAAAAAABSI/JueaGw2UmBcF7czNRMEUiae1YxAFQY-yACLcBGAs/s1600/Tools.png), or [this "Automation" window](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-1cipbKQtmNc/W0RCQ8jYXBI/AAAAAAAABQU/Ly6Be_cD6iIzHsXiYI5WKv-KFPVZSPDeQCLcBGAs/s1600/EmailC.png)? (Assuming I found the correct software.)

Comment: @user1686, the second one -"Automation" window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simple answer is that the program wasn't written to do that. It does not support "connected" IMAP operation – it only uses IMAP for grabbing all messages into the local system, exactly like it would use POP. All folders it shows are local.

---

It is not possible to access stored mail using SMTP alone – the protocol *only* supports sending new messages and nothing else. If your program is accessing stored messages, it must be doing so through IMAP or some other protocol.

(Sure, the server address might happen to be "smtp.something", but the program is still accessing it via IMAP, not via SMTP.)

Comment: Thanks I was able to move the mail via some other application. The application which I was using earlier wasn't doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Can this also be reflected to its web mail?
According to my test, for IMAP accounts in Outlook desktop client, some subfolders are only saved locally and will not be synchronized with the mail server or other mail clients.[image]